# Firebase CLI commands always give exit code 1

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I am trying to use firebase, however, each and every command of the `firebase-tools` is exiting with a 1 status code.

```
> firebase login    
> echo $?
1
```

I've tried `npm install -g firebase-tools` and its `sudo` counterpart without any luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of the Firebase tools are you running (`firebase --version`)?

Comment: This command also exits with 1. Is there another way to know ?

Comment: Ok, so the `package.json` file in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/` says 2.2.0

Comment: Does it create a `firebase-debug.log` file in the directory you're running the command in? There should be some more information there.

Comment: @ChrisRaynor. No, it doesn't.

Comment: Try `firebase login --interactive` to force an interactive shell in case the TTY detection is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that node itself wasn't working. Any attempt to do anything related to node was exiting with 1. The following fixed it:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```